# Apache Cordova and noVNC library, problem with Map() Object running

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, vnc

I'm trying to create an application which connects with X11 VNC server, with Cordova.
I found [this library](https://github.com/novnc/noVNC), and I've included it in the apache cordova project. This work good on browser simulator, but, when I launch the debug app on Android Device, I receive this error from the library:

[image]

I think on Android there's some problem about the Map() object, but I don't have a solution. I can't understand how to solve this problem. 
There's some solution about this? Or if exist other library for cordova to have a VNC Connection?